# I can't access my website anymore

Tags: website, wifi-configuration

I'm developing a website and during development, I suddenly couldn't load the page anymore. I've already had this issue once, this time it fixed itself after some time, but I don't want to wait for it this time.
I don't receive any error, but after some minutes the browser says "connection timed out"
I've already tried to access the page from a Linux pc, two windows pcs and my mobile phone. If I use the wifi to access it from mobile, it doesn't work, but with mobile data it works. I've also tested it with a website called "downforeveryoneorjustme.com" , it said the website is up.
Here's the url: http://cars.bplaced.net
Thanks!

Comment: At the moment the website works for me. If it wasn't a stub, I would suspect your entire question is spam.

Comment: That's the problem, the website works for everyone but not for me

Comment: [`traceroute`/`tracert`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) (depending on the OS) may tell you where the problem is. You can [edit] the question and post the results (but you may want to obfuscate them, this requires some knowledge on which addresses to obfuscate and which not).

Comment: Maybe it's your ISP, since your phone probably uses a different ISP. Using HTTP is not a good idea and browsers have begun penalizing it, and maybe your ISP too.

Comment: Is the website hosted on your LAN or with a hosting provider?  Also, how did you set up DNS for it?

Comment: Also, does it work from an alternate browser on your PC! I've not come across it for a while now, but historically browser caching could cause issues - in which case clear your browsing history.

Answer (score 0):

The site is 404 now. There are many reasons why an error message could appear. These include:

- The URL or its content (such as files or images) was either deleted or moved (without adjusting any internal links accordingly)
- The URL was written incorrectly (during the creation process or a redesign), linked incorrectly, or typed into the browser incorrectly
- The server responsible for the website is not running or the connection is broken
- The requested domain name can’t be converted to an IP by the domain name system (DNS)
- The entered domain name doesn’t exist (anymore)

Recheck your server, hosting and domain link